# manipulating entry text value in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to add the word "Search Here !" inside the entry which will be disappeared once the user starts typing in the entry!

same like what we see in facebook web page "What's on ur mind"

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=NONE):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.entry = Entry(self.frame)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You;'ve told us what you want' the code to do, but you haven't asked a question. What's the question? Are you asking us to write the code for you? Are you having a problem with a specific aspect of the solution? Do you know how to set up bindings? Do you know how to insert text? ...?

Comment: thanx bryan, u r right, I actually dont know what is exactly my question.
I should have read more before I asked such question.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle key events for the `Entry` widget and erase the contents when the first key event occurs:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=NONE):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.entry = Entry(self.frame)
        self.entry.modified = False
        self.entry.insert(0, "Search Here!")
        self.entry.bind("<Key>", self.entry_key)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def entry_key(self, event):
        if not self.entry.modified:
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
            self.entry.modified = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

To detect the first change I have bound and initialised to `False` an attribute named `modified` to the `Entry` widget instance. When the first key event occurs the content of the entry box is deleted and the `modified` attribute is set to `True`, which prevents clearing of the content on subsequent key events.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use "StringVar" to set or get the text:

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=NONE):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        my_entry = StringVar()
        my_entry.set("Search here")
        self.entry = Entry(self.frame, text=my_entry)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't _need_ to use a `StringVar` -- you can get and set the text without it. In fact, I would argue you should never use a `StringVar` unless you need it for some of it's other features besides just getting and setting (such as tracing it, or linking two widgets together)